# How to change `\autocite{x}` of a footnote style to link bibliography with an author-year label?

Tags: biblatex, citing, oscola

I produce documents with a recommended reading lists using `\nocite{*}` and the bibliography style [OSCOLA](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/oscola).

OSCOLA uses normally only footnotes, but still a bibliography can be printed.

I would like to put now few references to some items in the recommended reading list using an author-year label. How can I configure biblatex to produce such a label and link it to the bibliography? I use pandoc to draft content, so the `\autocite{x}` command is imposed.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=oscola,autocite=plain]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{test.bib}


\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@online{simon2018,
  url = {https://www.euractiv.com/section/energy/news/smart-meter-woes-hold-back-digitalisation-of-eu-power-sector/},
  date = {2019-01-29},
  author = {Frédéric Simon},
  title = {Smart meter woes hold back digitalisation of EU power sector},
  journaltitle = {EURACTIV},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\title{Recommended Readings}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Context}

This has been noted previously \autocite{simon2018}.

% References
\nocite{*} % include all elements from the bibliography
\printbibliography[title={Recommended Reading}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Aimed Output

> This has been noted previously (Frédéric Simon, 2018).

When I configure biblatex with `citestyle=authoryear`, I get the error:

> Package etoolbox Error: Toggle 'cbx@postnoteprinted' undefined.

Comment: The OSCOLA style doesn't really lend itself to author-year citations (note for example that the year usually comes after the title in the bibliography, making it harder for your readers to match a author-year citation label to a partciular bibliography entry; the fact that years may be formatted differently [in round brackets, sometimes with additional test, in square brackets] makes that even harder because there is nothing they eye can hold on to find the year). ...

Comment: More TeXnically `(biblatex)-oscola`'s implementation somehow relies on you using the bibliography and citation style together, so switching to a different `citestyle` is extremely tricky and would need additional code fixes.

Comment: @moewe `oxnotes` could be an option for non-lawyers. Court decisions and legislation don't need bibliographies, legal texts have Table of Cases and Table of Statutes at the front for legal authority cited, and in all cases the 'author' of a decision or statute is implied (Court or Crown/Parliament) and obvious to practitioners in the jurisdiction, so an authoryear style would be redundant and use much ink (and time - hence the footnoting style in OSCOLA). For non-lawyers, though, `oxnotes` helps greatly.

Comment: The eye becomes used to the structure, _Page v Smith_ [1996] AC 155, and is able to take it in at a glance, such that _Page v Smith_, [1996] AC 155 Canadian-style is disruptive and a shock, and vice-versa for Canadians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oxnotes` style implements BL-OSCOLA in a (non-legal) humanities-friendly way:

[image: oxnotes]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{UNGA_Res2222, 
  institution  = {UNGA},
  title        = {Treaty on Principles Governing the Activities of States in the Exploration and Use of Outer Space, including the Moon and Other Celestial Bodies}, 
  instrument_no= {RES 2222 (XXI)}, 
  date         = {1966-12-19},
  entrysubtype = {undoc},
  tabulate = {unres},
  }
@online{simon2018,
  url = {https://www.euractiv.com/section/energy/news/smart-meter-woes-hold-back-digitalisation-of-eu-power-sector/},
  date = {2019-01-29},
  author = {Frédéric Simon},
  title = {Smart meter woes hold back digitalisation of EU power sector},
  journaltitle = {EURACTIV},
}
@jurisdiction{antaios85,
title = {Antaios Compania Naviera S.A. v.
Salen Rederierna A.B. (The Nema)},
shorttitle = {The Nema},
date = {1985},
reporter = {A.C.},
pages = {191},
court = {H.L.},
additionalreports = {[1984] 3 WLR 592 and (1984) 128 SJ 564
and [1984] 3 All ER 229 and
[1984] 2 Lloyd’s Rep 235},
keywords = {gb},
}
@jurisdiction{corr08,
title = {Corr v. I.B.C. Vehicles Ltd.},
keywords = {gb},
date = {2008},
number = {[2008] UKHL 13},
journaltitle = {A.C.},
volume = {1},
pages = {884},
options = {year-essential=true},
institution = {HL},
shorttitle = {Corr},
pagination = {[]},
}
@jurisdiction{page96,
title = {Page v Smith},
usera = {gb},
date = {1996},
journaltitle = {AC},
pages = {155},
institution = {HL},
}
@inbook{pila10,
author = {Pila, Justine},
editor = {Dutton, William H. and Jeffreys, Paul W.},
booktitle= {World Wide Research: Reshaping the
Sciences and Humanities in the
Century of Information},
publisher= {MIT Press},
date = {2010},
title = {The Value of Authorship in the
Digital Environment},
pages = {210--231},
}
@book{leviathan,
author = {Hobbes, Thomas},
title = {Leviathan},
publisher = {Penguin},
date = {1985},
origdate = {1651},
location = {Harmondsworth},
}
@article{craig05,
author = {Craig, Paul},
title = {Theory {`Pure Theory'}
and Values in Public Law},
date = {2005},
journaltitle = {P.L.},
pages = {440},
}

\end{filecontents*}  
  
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[style=oxnotes,%oscola,
                        citestyle=authoryear,
        indexing=cite,
        backend=biber,
        ecli=yes,
        babel=hyphen,
%        autocite=footnote,
        ]{biblatex}
        
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}

text \autocite{UNGA_Res2222}

This has been noted previously \autocite{simon2018}.

...like in \cite{antaios85}, and two other cases in the House of Lords, \cite{corr08} and \cite{page96}.

Article \autocite{craig05}, book \autocite{pila10} and old book \autocite{leviathan}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```